# How can i referral user on my website using facebook register?

Tags: facebook

I have social game website and my user want to get some benefit when they invite there friends. I only use login with facebook and register with facebook only with minimum detail  `fullname` and `email`

My idea is using **referral** but i have no idea how i can do that. website register is on click step.

```
if(!$user) { 
    header("Location:$loginUrl"); 
} else {
    // check if user is register else login
    // if not register then register and take them to home page.
    $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $user_info['first_name']); 
    $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $user_info['last_name']); 
    $email = $user_info['email'];
    // all register process goes here
}
```

So please any idea anyone can give me about referral if u need more detail about my register  i can give.

Thank you.

Comment: I would like to know this idea. Well if it was native register i would have helped.

Comment: just create a unique id for each user and then create a ref url for each user. something like this www.yourdomain.com/ref/?id=unique_id_user if someone enters this url you just check if the id really exists on your database, if so you save it on your session till the new user signs up, after the new users sign up process on your website, you're ready to give the bonus to the owner of the share url